# Google Sheet Conditional Formating - Color Scale Rows of a table depending of the text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I don't find the solution to set a conditional formating with a color scale applied to a range which could be variable from a table to another one.
Could you please help me to find the way to do that as in the sheet "Color Scale with Conditional Formating" where I've colored the fields as I would like with conditional formating rules?

Here after the link to the example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UyW12WwG9sJUF0ZhnHGP9adgbY3xWUpj4kM9-ASN2WE/edit#gid=1897261118

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello Vince, what would be the criteria for that colour scale you're trying to set in different tables? I see how you painted the example, but I don't get how `it could be variable` - thanks!

Comment: Hello, in fact for:
- the first column: condition if text "Prod" or " NO prod" or "Others" paint with color --> I've found the solution
- others columns: must be linked with the first column and have a color scale linked with this first column. But I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmm, the exact shape I don't know if it's possible. If you are going to add more rows or columns and want to keep that 3 rows alternated colors, you can benefit from row.

In my example starting in Col V you can use something like this:

=(MOD(ROW(W4),3)=1)*(W4<>"")

[image]

And you can add the three rules:

[image]

You can add this for the black and white:

=(V3<>"")*(($V3="Cluster 1")+($X3="Total"))

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. Your solution do perfectly that I'd need. Regards